# syntax error, unexpected identifier "Value", expecting variable (symfony)

Tags: database, symfony

Im problème connecting in my database image in under.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inject EntityManagerInterface as a parameter of your function blog().

It could be :

```
public function blog(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
$blogs = $entityManager->getRepository(Blog::class)->findAll();
}
```